# Meteor JS with CSS variables and IE support

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, meteor

My problem is, that I have a meteor application, and the clearest and simplest way to change style is to use CSS variables. 
BUT: IE doesn't support them at all, so I had to  write a helper function, what changes the style on every template creation, and user interaction.
That helper function is slow, and ugly, so I want to specify the helper function only for IE, and use CSS variables in others browsers. 
-How can I specify before the build if the browser is IE use IEspec.css,
Other case use nonIEspec.css?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know meteor build process, but you can add this in your  index.html:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Regarding variables IE doesn't support them, just Edge 15+.

> In Edge 15, nested calculations with css variables are not computed
>   and are ignored see bug In Edge 15 animations with css variables may
>   cause the webpage to crash see bug In Edge 15 is not possible to use
>   css variables in pseudo elements see bug

You have pure css variables or is something like SASS/LESS? Maybe there is a compiler which make them css 1, 2 or 3.

Check compatibility [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=variables)

Comment: Thank you, I made at this way, and seems like work now. But Not because of : 

<!--[if IE]> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-only.css" /> <![endif]--> 

It works because of the setStyle helper function. Because In explorer the CSS variables are undefined, but helper function the elements gets a defined property. And that helper function runs only if the browser is IE or Edge. So actually dont need to check browser in index.html